# Remove TabBarItem highlight

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar

I have a `UITabBar` based application, on one TabBar Button I have a navigation controller. When I move to navigation controller, tab bar highlight option needs to be removed. No tab bar buttons should be selected.

How could I make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to take a look at the "Managing the Finished and Selected Image" task's section of the [UITabBarItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change tabBar index then use

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:index];
```

of if you dont want to show selected index then just hide tabBar.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to show UITabBar always. 
I added navigationController in TabBarController using **setViewControllers:animated:** instance method.
When i change **selectedIndex** another Tab button highlighted. i dont wan't any highlighted tab button when i move to table detail view.

Comment: You cant do this...because you are in navigation controller..and table detail view also in navigation controller....