# Jump to another ViewController in the UITabBarViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm developing an iOS application and I have a problem:
The structure of my app is the next:

- UITabBar

  - UINavigationController for listing places (1) and, when I select one of them, another ViewController appear with the details(2)
  - UINavigationController for listing my inbox(3) and when I select, another ViewController appear with the details(4).

I want to do the next:
When I push one button in the view of place's details(2), loading a new view for the details of the conversation(4) and this one has to be like a normal view with its navigation for view(3) as if I'd access through the view(3) and then (4).

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460013/remove-uitabbar-controller/12460244#12460244

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273563/hide-uitabbar-when-pushed-while-retaining-touch/11273959#11273959

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313820/change-the-selected-tabbar-index-on-button-click/12313858#12313858

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490665/remove-tabbaritem-highlight/12491327#12491327

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From View 3 detailButtonTapped event call. 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];

self is the 3rd Viewcontroller that has the detail button and is already pushed into a navigation controller or has a navigationcontroller associated with it by the init method of navigation controller initWithRootViewController:3rdController